# cancel JComboBox actionEvent

Tags: java, swing, events, jcombobox

I'm writing a gui program and have an AbstractAction for a Jbutton that opens a file.  In a JComboBox I have a list of the files that have been opened.  The AbstractAction for the JComboBox will change back to any of the files that have been opened.  When I update the list for a JComboBox though the action fires.

So when I actually open a file the JComboBox action fires, and when I use the JComboBox the action fires once, then a second time when updating.

Is there a way i can stop the event when just updating the JComboBox list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can remove the listener and then re-add it. Or you could have it's actions controlled by a boolean field.

Comment: Is removing, re-adding, more efficient than just letting the event be called, and having a check inside the AbstractAction actionPerformed method? Currently I just check if the new file's name is equal to updated, and if it is I skip most of what happens in the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the design, particularly in separation of concers: don't think view-with-two-actions, instead think many-views-change-state-of-single-data.

In pseudo-code something like:

```
// data class
public class MyOpenFilesBean {

    private File currentFile; 

    public void setCurrentFile(File current) {
         File old = getCurrentFile();
         this.currentFile = current;
         firePropertyChange("currentFile", old, getCurrentFile());
    }

    public File getCurrentFile() {
        return currentFile;
    }

}  

// view wiring (view --> data)

Action open = new AbstractAction(...) {

      public void actionPerformed(...) {
          File choosenFile = // grab it from whereever in the view
          myOpenFileBean.setCurrentFile(choosenFile);
      }  

};
myButton.setAction(open);
myComboBox.setAction(open);

// view wiring (data --> view)

PropertyChangeListener l = new PropertyChangeListener() {
     public void propertyChanged(...) {
         if ("currentFile".equals(evt.getPropertyName()) {
               // a method implemented to update f.i. the combo selection  
               updateView((File) evt.getNewValue());
         }
     } 
};
myOpenFileBean.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
```